# Chrome browser full Kiosk mode in Linux (Puppy Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, google-chrome, cron, script

Let me just say thanks in advance.

I am having issues getting google-chrome browser into full KIOSK MODE with no browser bar on a linux platform

Looking through the google forums I have found numerous postings on how to get Chrome to show full kiosk mode BUT

tried to execute with --kiosk but doesnt seem to get the job done.

I dont know if this is platform specific or not, but any useful information would help.

I know F11 will display the browser in full kiosk mode, with no browser bar BUT is there a way to do this with a linux script and no need for a monkey pressing F11??

Answer (score 1):

See the [Issue 23145](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23145) on Google Code for this feature. Looks like you can get this by running it with `--kiosk --incognito --no-context-menu` to get what you want.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I will give it a test tonight or in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: Ok this does work, but I want every bar gone.  incognito seems to remove 1 portion of the actual bar.